# How to count files of a certain type in a folder on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, mp3, music

I'm in the process of backing up some of my data. After (presumably) updating my back up music folder on my external hard drive, I check the size of both my back up music folder and my standard music folder and they differ.

A possible reason for this is that the standard music folder is updated with album art fagotry. As such, I want to be able to count how many mp3s (I can live with ignoring the other music formats) I have on a folder. How can I do this?

Other work arounds to guarantee that I have the same music files on both folders are also welcome.

I'm on Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Comment: In **cmd** use a command such as `dir *.mp3 | find "File(s)"` in each directory. This will give you two consecutive lines to compare. (NB Tested on XP - it is possible that W7 changed the summary line format, but it will be trivial to alter the **find** string if so.)

Comment: and easier *cmd* is dir /s *.mp3 | find /c "mp3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by:

- typing `*.mp3` in the search box
- see the file count at the bottom of the window

[image]

(PS. I'm not showing you my music collection :P)

---

If you want to compare the 2 folders, use the technique [here](http://improvingsoftware.com/2013/09/09/how-to-diff-two-folders-from-a-windows-command-prompt/). It basically uses the command line and robocopy (included with win8).

Copied and pasted from above link:

```
ROBOCOPY “\\FileShare\SourceFolder” “\\FileShare\ComparisonFolder” /e /l /ns /njs /njh /ndl /fp /log:reconcile.txt
```

> Explanation of the command switches used above:
>
> - /e  Recurse through sub-directories (including empty ones)
> - /l  Don’t modify or copy files, log differences only
> - /fp  Include the full path of files in log (only necessary if you omit /ndl)
> - /ns  Don’t include file sizes in log
> - /ndl  Don’t include folders in log
> - /njs   Don’t include Job Summary
> - /njh   Don’t include Job Header
> - /log:reconcile.txt   Write log to reconcile.txt (Recreate if exists)
> - /log+: reconcile.txt   (Optional variant) Write log to reconcile.txt (Append if exists)

Comment: Perfect. Selecting the files was unnecessary, though. The file count shows up at the bottom without selecting them.

Comment: @GitGud you're right. I was on my Win7 laptop, so I didn't know exactly, but I've added a screenshot now (in win8 :)